# Vector of Row Names where a certain column meets criteria

Tags: r

I want to create a `1:X` vector that contains the `rownames` from a `data.frame` where a certain column meets a given criteria.

An example `data.frame` would be:

```
Rowname       ColumnA
Height        2.6
Weight        2.5
Length        2.4
Diameter      2.3
```

If my criteria was `ColumnA >= 2.5`, then I would want a vector that would be equivalent to manually creating a vector of `c("Height","Weight")`. I have a `data.frame` that has over 1000 `rownames` in it, so I want to be able to plug in a value and get the `rownames` of the variables that meet my criteria for `ColumnA` stored in a vector. I will use this new vector as a way to create a new model that only uses those variables as predictor variables.

Comment: You may try `split` i.e. `split(df1$Rowname, df1$ColumnA>=2.5)` or if you need only the rownames, `rownames(df1)[df1$ColumnA >=2.5)]`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a logical index (`df1$columnA >= 2.5`) to subset the `rownames` as a `vector`.

```
rownames(df1)[df1$ColumnA >=2.5]
```